# Why is multiple item drop not working on listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I create a playlist for media player.

Follow my code:

Xaml:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mePlayer" Margin="64,0,90,61"  ></MediaElement>
<ListBox x:Name="listbox4" Background="Salmon"   BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Drop="listbox4_Drop"  >
</ListBox>
<Button x:Name="load" Content="Load" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Click="load_Click" Margin="184,285,0,0"/>
```

Xaml.cs:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> fileDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();   

private void load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.DefaultExt = ".mp3";
    ofd.Filter = "All|*.*";
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < ofd.FileNames.Length; i++)
        {
            var filePath = ofd.FileNames[i];
            var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);
            listbox4.Items.Add(fileName);
            listbox4.SelectedItem = fileName;
        }
    }
}


private void listbox4_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {

        string[] droppedFilePaths =
            e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

        foreach (string droppedFilePath in droppedFilePaths)
        {
         for (int i = 0; i < droppedFilePaths.Length; i++)
            {
                var filePath = droppedFilePaths[i];
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);
                listbox4.Items.Add(fileName);
                listbox4.SelectedItem = fileName;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

It's working single file drop but while I drop multiple file then it's not added on listbox.

Multiple loaded file is loaded but multiple file will not dropped.

**How can I drop multiple file on listbox?**

Comment: I copy pasted your code in a new WPF project and dropping multiple files did "work", so to speak. Your code needs a bit of tweaking but, overall it did "work". So I'm not sure what problem you're facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am not able to replicate the problem you listed I currently can not help you in that regard. Though, I can help you where I see fit.

Your current Drop method has an extra loop that multiples the number of items you add to the listbox.

Your current method:

```
    private void listbox4_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {

            string[] droppedFilePaths =
                e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

            foreach (string droppedFilePath in droppedFilePaths)
            {
                //if you keep this loop, you will all the dropped files for each dropped file
                //therefore, if I dropped 3 files, I'd get 9 entries in the listbox
                //if I dropped 4 files, I'd get 16 entries and so on...
                for (int i = 0; i < droppedFilePaths.Length; i++)//this has to go
                {//this has to go
                    var filePath = droppedFilePaths[i];//this needs to be a different variable since "i" will no longer exist
                    var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    //fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);
                    listbox4.Items.Add(fileName);
                    listbox4.SelectedItem = fileName;
                }//this has to go

            }
        }
    }
```

Refactored (using the ForEach)

```
    private void blaze_125_listbox4_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {

            string[] droppedFilePaths =
                e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

            foreach (string droppedFilePath in droppedFilePaths)
            {
                var filePath = droppedFilePath;
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                //fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);
                listbox4.Items.Add(fileName);
                listbox4.SelectedItem = fileName;
            }

        }
    }
```

This would also work (using the ForLoop)

```
    private void blaze_125_listbox4_Drop_anotherSpin(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] droppedFilePaths =
                e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

            for (int i = 0; i < droppedFilePaths.Length; i++)
            {
                var filePath = droppedFilePaths[i];
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                //fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);
                listbox4.Items.Add(fileName);
                listbox4.SelectedItem = fileName;
            }
        }
    }
```

Slimmer

```
    private void blaze_125_listbox4_Drop_Slimmer(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] droppedFilePaths =
                e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

            foreach (string droppedFilePath in droppedFilePaths)
            {
                listbox4.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(droppedFilePath));
            }
        }
    }
```

Using the dictionary to store items, and to update the list

```
    Dictionary<string, string> fileDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private void blaze_125_listbox4_Drop_Slimmer(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] droppedFilePaths =
                e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

            foreach (string droppedFilePath in droppedFilePaths)
            {
                //listbox4.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(droppedFilePath));//don't need this anymore

                //Check if the file is already in the dictionary.
                //Check by looking up the key, and by looking up the value too.
                if (fileDictionary.ContainsKey(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(droppedFilePath)) || fileDictionary.ContainsValue(droppedFilePath))
                {
                    //no need to add this file, it's already in the dictionary
                    //if you try to add a file with a KEY identical to a KEY that already exists in the dictionary,
                    //it will throw an exception
                    //A dictionary can contain the same value multiple times, but it can not contain the same key more than once.
                }
                else
                {
                    //the file is not listed in the dictionary, so lets add it
                    fileDictionary.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(droppedFilePath), droppedFilePath);
                }
            }
        }

        //Now lets call the method in charge of updating the listbox 
        UpdateTheListbox(fileDictionary, listbox4);
    }

    private void UpdateTheListbox(Dictionary<string, string> incomingDictionary, ListBox listboxToModify)
    {
        listboxToModify.Items.Clear();//clear all the items in the list
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in incomingDictionary)
        {
            listboxToModify.Items.Add(item.Key);
        }
        //this method should probably be optimized because if your listBox already contains a large number of items
        //it may be quicker to only add the missing items, instead of reverting back to an empty list, and adding all the items to it again.
        //Though I'll leave this up to you to implement. We'll be here to answer questions if you have a hard time doing it.
    }
```

Updated method to maintain the selected item if there is a selected item

```
    private void UpdateTheListboxMaintainExistingSelection(Dictionary<string, string> incomingDictionary, ListBox listboxToModify)
    {
        var preSelectedItem = listboxToModify.SelectedItem;//store the current selection

        listboxToModify.Items.Clear();//clear all the items in the list
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in incomingDictionary)
        {
            listboxToModify.Items.Add(item.Key);
        }
        //this method should probably be optimized because if your listBox already contains a large number of items
        //it may be quicker to only add the missing items, instead of reverting back to an empty list, and adding all the items to it again.
        //Though I'll leave this up to you to implement. We'll be here to answer questions if you have a hard time doing it.

        //Maintain the selected item if there was one
        if (preSelectedItem != null)
        {
            listboxToModify.SelectedItem = preSelectedItem;
        }
    }
```

To maintain the selection or select the last item if there was no selection

```
    private void UpdateTheListboxMaintainExistingOrSelectLastAdded(Dictionary<string, string> incomingDictionary, ListBox listboxToModify)
    {
        var preSelectedItem = listboxToModify.SelectedItem;//store the current selection

        listboxToModify.Items.Clear();//clear all the items in the list
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in incomingDictionary)
        {
            listboxToModify.Items.Add(item.Key);
        }
        //this method should probably be optimized because if your listBox already contains a large number of items
        //it may be quicker to only add the missing items, instead of reverting back to an empty list, and adding all the items to it again.
        //Though I'll leave this up to you to implement. We'll be here to answer questions if you have a hard time doing it.


        if (preSelectedItem != null)
        {
            //Maintain the selected item if there was one
            listboxToModify.SelectedItem = preSelectedItem;
        }
        else
        {
            //select the last item in the listbox if nothing was pre-selected
            listboxToModify.SelectedItem = listboxToModify.Items[listboxToModify.Items.Count - 1];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its working fine.But **Why is the list and select the last item?**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. For what it's worth, the ForEach and/or the ForLoop could easily be slimmed down a bit more. `filePath` and `fileName` are not really necessary. `listbox4.Items.Add(fileName)` is where you add the item to the listbox, and `listbox4.SelectedItem = filename` is where you are changing the active selection in the listbox.

Comment: When i load then auto select the last item of listbox.

See

http://i.imgur.com/5OaHuFV.jpg

Comment: I'm still unsure about your question so... *why are those 2 lines of code where they currently are within the method?* `.Items.Add()` needs to be there because you can't add something you don't have yet. and the same logic applies to `.SelectedItem = ""`, you can't select something that is not yet in the box. Though I don't think you should be selecting anything in that drop method, at least not unless you first verify if something is already selected and/or playing. But hey, the user experience is up to you.

Comment: Ok
Thanks for solve this problem

I will ask new question later.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, Facebook is a privacy void I did not sign up for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121563/discussion-between-blaze-125-and-tania-akter).

Comment: Same file can not add more time.
I use your 3rd code named (using the ForLoop).
And I use this code
`fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);`

Its avoid same file add same time

Comment: I need file dictionary for play items.
So I use it.But dictionary is avoid samefile on same time

Comment: I tried opening a "chat session" with you to avoid the Facebook deal but I don't know if you got notified or how you get to it or whatever... so I'll update my answer with a new code snippet that will answer your question about the dictionary.

Comment: Please edit my project & send me.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4E6MbGGj8OdbXpTTkJCNDRuYVE

Email: sabbir0186@gmail.com

Buddy I am waiting for your email.